# Replacing | in JavaScript Issues

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to replace the character `|` with the character plus spaces before and after the character, however it ends up putting `|` between every letter. This is how I tried to do it:

```
content.replace(new RegExp("|", "g"), " | ");
```

Comment: You probably need to escape the bar. That's a social symbol in regex isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

`|` means *or* in regex.

You need to escape it:

```
content.replace(/\|/g, " | ");
```

Comment: 590k rep :O How can you even...

Comment: Thank you Master ! It works perfectly.

Comment: How in-place ..?